# Connecting remotely to MySQL Database but saving the data in a local MySQL Database C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

my first question here, hope you guys can help.

I have a C# winforms "server" application that has a local MySQL database.
I also have a "client" application that I need to connect to the remote MySQL server, I do know how to do this, my question is this:

Is it possible to connect to the remote MySQL DB read from specific tables certain information, and then if that information is true for that specific client the client should copy or add that information on a local MySQL DB it is running on localhost?

So basically, conenct to remote SQL server, read data and then copy that data to local DB from the client side.

I hope this makes sense, thank you for your help or advise.

Comment: why you need local servers?

Comment: @Damith Probably for offline use, paired with online synchronization. I see probably, but it's pure conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

You already described the answer in your own question. Yes, it is possible. After you read data, make sure it is valid etc. Insert it into the local DB table.

Comment: I guess I have, thank you thinking about yur answer and @Sylca's answer I will probably start with a SELECT query on the remote server string and then an UPDATE/INSERT on the local connection string if the conditions are being met?

Comment: Im also wondering, what happens if there will be a connection issues while INSERTING/UPDATING the local database, will it restart when a connection is available again or will it create DB issues?
There will be 1000's of rows I want to store on the local DB,will this be the best way or what would you guys recommend?

Comment: @Kevin You would have to handle those cases. It will create DB issues if you do not design it well. Also, storing a large amount of data in local DB is not efficient I believe. Plus, there is the issue of remote and local DB being out of sync. I would use remote DB all the way.

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin you can connect to any online database if you have correct connection credentials.

If you change the connection string you can.

Also you can have n number of database connection no matter it is online or offline

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, just use different connection strings:

server side:

```
string cs1 = @"server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;uid=xxxxx;password=xxxxx;database=xxxx;port=3306;charset=utf8;Allow User Variables=True";
```

localhost side:

```
string cs2 = @"server=localhost;uid=xxxxx;password=xxxx;database=xxxxxxxxx;port=3306;charset=utf8";
```